# Как сделать ссылку с сегодняшней датой?

Tags: php, datetime

Делаю ссылки в ввиде `http://site.ru/main.php?sid=<?= $_GET['sid'] ?>`
Но понадобилась нужда делать ссылки в таком виде

```
http://site.ru/main.php?sid=<?= $_GET['sid'] ?>&date=СЕГОДНЯШНЯЯДАТА&datedva=ДАТАМЕСЯЦНАЗАД
```

Как это можно реализовать в формате 19.08.2019 ?  пытался через &date неполучилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$d = getdate();
$curdMinusOnemonths = date("d.m.Y", strtotime("-1 months")); или $d->modify('-1 month');
```

---

```
http://site.ru/main.php?sid=<?= $_GET['sid'] ?>&date="$d[mday].$d[mon].$d[year]"&datedva=$curdMinusOnemonths
```